# Order of execution of annotations in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to load some properties from property files in Spring boot but also want to access them using a list. I am unsure about the order in which the class member will be initialised.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigurationM{

   @Value("${propA}")
   private String propA;

   @Value("${propB}")
   private String propB;

   private List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(propA, propB);


}
```

Does @Value annotation injects value before the list is initialised? How is the order of evaluation determined when the class is loaded while using annotations?

Comment: Injection happens when the object is being created. Instead of relying on the order, `@PostConstruct` should better serve your needs here.

Comment: My proposal to change question title to: "How to initialize a List of String properties in Spring?"

Comment: tags: spring, properties, spel ;)

Comment: better: "how to load (single) properties into a list of string?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does @Value annotation injects value before the list is initialised?

Unfortunately, no! The "instance initializer"(class/object body) is executed prior to the "constructor", and spring has no chance to inject there anything.

> How is the order of evaluation determined when the class is loaded while using annotations?

-> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans

---

You could also evict the `@PostConstruct` with pure [spel](/questions/tagged/spel):

```
// pure (built-in) SpEL:
@Value("#{{'${propA}', '${propB}'}}")
private List<String> list;
    
// Java < 9
@Value("#{ T(java.util.Arrays).asList('${propA}', '${propB}')}")
private List<String> listJ8;
    
// Java > 8
@Value("#{ T(java.util.List).of('${propA}', '${propB}')}")
private List<String> listJ9;
```